# Meteor 1.8, Blaze & i18n Localization

Tags: meteor, localization, internationalization, meteor-blaze, i18next

So far it seems both Tap & Universe don't work for me with Meteor 1.8 and Blaze

Install for Universe:

```
meteor add universe:i18n universe:i18n-blaze
```

Install for Tap:

```
meteor add tap:i18n tap:i18n-db
```

I have the folllowing configuration files (both Tap and Universe):

/i18n/en.i18n.json

```
{
    "hello": "hello world"
}
```

/i18n/fr.i18n.json

```
{
    "hello": "bonjour"
}
```

The Blaze template file with `Tap`
/client/blaze-template-tap.html

```html
<template name="BlazeTemplateTap">
  {{_ "hello"}}
</template>
```

/client/blaze-template-universe.html

```html
<template name="BlazeTemplateUniverse">
  {{__ "hello"}}
</template>
```

Also, with Universe (only) I need to register namespace in template:
/client/blaze-template-universe.js

```
Template.BlazeTemplateUniverse.bindI18nNamespace('hello');
```

The result is alway just no matter if I change the localization between English and French via the

```
chrome://settings/languages
```

and/or the `Quick Language Switcher` Chrome extension.

// Chrome Result:

```
hello world
```

So connection (both in Tap and Universe) is made between the Blaze template `{{__ "hello"}}` and the en.i18n.json file `{ "hello" "hello world" }` because it's displaying "hello world".  But something is not clicking when I try to switch languages in Chrome.

I need help getting Tap or Universe (or even i18next, which I have not tried) to display different languages within Blaze.

Comment: Can you please add to your description how you switch languages in chrome for reproduction purposes?